# Connect one key to another key in XSL file

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying connect values of `RestaurantId` in `ReviewApplication/Reviews/Review` node to `Restaurant/Name` in `Companys/Company/Restaurants/Restaurant` node in the XSL file, but I'm not sure how to do, I've tried `<choose>` and `<key>` but it's currently not working for me.. I really appreciate any input!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
                version="2.0">
    <xsl:key name="firstname" match="ReviewApplication/Reviews/Review/UserName" use="ReviewApplication/Users/User/FirstName" />

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"></xsl:output>
  
    <xsl:template match="/ReviewApplication">
    

        <html><head><title>Reviews with Recommendations</title></head><body>

            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>RestaurantName</th>
                    <th>FirstName</th>
                    <th>Rating</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="/ReviewApplication/Reviews/Review">

                    <xsl:variable name="restaurantname" select="/ReviewApplication/Companys/Company/Restaurants/Restaurant/Name" />
                    <xsl:variable name="name" select="../../Users/User/FirstName" />

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="RestaurantId"></xsl:value-of>
                        </td>



                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="UserName"></xsl:value-of>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Rating"></xsl:value-of>
                        </td>


                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body></html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ReviewApplication>
   <Users>
      <User>
         <UserName>username1</UserName>
         <FirstName>first1</FirstName>
         <LastName>last1</LastName>
      </User>
      <User>
         <UserName>username2</UserName>
         <FirstName>first2</FirstName>
         <LastName>last2</LastName>
      </User>
      <User>
         <UserName>username3</UserName>
         <FirstName>first3</FirstName>
         <LastName>last3</LastName>
      </User>
      <User>
         <UserName>username4</UserName>
         <FirstName>first4</FirstName>
         <LastName>last4</LastName>
      </User>
      <User>
         <UserName>username5</UserName>
         <FirstName>first5</FirstName>
         <LastName>last5</LastName>
      </User>
   </Users>
   <Companys>
      <Company>
         <CompanyName>companyname1</CompanyName>
         <About>aboutcompany1</About>
         <Restaurants>
            <Restaurant>
               <RestaurantId>restaurantid1</RestaurantId>
               <Name>restaurant1</Name>
            </Restaurant>
            <Restaurant>
               <RestaurantId>restaurantid2</RestaurantId>
               <Name>restaurant2</Name>
            </Restaurant>
            <Restaurant>
               <RestaurantId>restaurantid3</RestaurantId>
               <Name>restaurant3</Name>
            </Restaurant>
         </Restaurants>
      </Company>
      <Company>
         <CompanyName>companyname2</CompanyName>
         <About>aboutcompany2</About>
         <Restaurants>
            <Restaurant>
               <RestaurantId>restaurantid4</RestaurantId>
               <Name>restaurant4</Name>
            </Restaurant>
            <Restaurant>
               <RestaurantId>restaurantid5</RestaurantId>
               <Name>restaurant5</Name>
            </Restaurant>
            <Restaurant>
               <RestaurantId>restaurantid6</RestaurantId>
               <Name>restaurant6</Name>
            </Restaurant>
         </Restaurants>
      </Company>
      <Company>
         <CompanyName>companyname3</CompanyName>
         <About>aboutcompany3</About>
         <Restaurants>
            <Restaurant>
               <RestaurantId>restaurantid7</RestaurantId>
               <Name>restaurant7</Name>
            </Restaurant>
            <Restaurant>
               <RestaurantId>restaurantid8</RestaurantId>
               <Name>restaurant8</Name>
            </Restaurant>
            <Restaurant>
               <RestaurantId>restaurantid9</RestaurantId>
               <Name>restaurant9</Name>
            </Restaurant>
         </Restaurants>
      </Company>
   </Companys>
   <Reviews>
      <Review>
         <UserName>username1</UserName>
         <RestaurantId>restaurantid1</RestaurantId>
         <Rating>4.0</Rating>
      </Review>
      <Review>
         <UserName>username1</UserName>
         <RestaurantId>restaurantid2</RestaurantId>
         <Rating>5.0</Rating>
      </Review>
      <Review>
         <UserName>username1</UserName>
         <RestaurantId>restaurantid4</RestaurantId>
         <Rating>4.0</Rating>
      </Review>
      <Review>
         <UserName>username1</UserName>
         <RestaurantId>restaurantid5</RestaurantId>
         <Rating>1.0</Rating>
      </Review>
      <Review>
         <UserName>username2</UserName>
         <RestaurantId>restaurantid1</RestaurantId>
         <Rating>2.0</Rating>
      </Review>
      <Review>
         <UserName>username2</UserName>
         <RestaurantId>restaurantid7</RestaurantId>
         <Rating>3.0</Rating>
      </Review>
      <Review>
         <UserName>username2</UserName>
         <RestaurantId>restaurantid8</RestaurantId>
         <Rating>4.0</Rating>
      </Review>
   </Reviews>
   <Recommendations>
      <Recommendation>
         <UserName>username1</UserName>
         <RestaurantId>restaurantid1</RestaurantId>
      </Recommendation>
      <Recommendation>
         <UserName>username1</UserName>
         <RestaurantId>restaurantid2</RestaurantId>
      </Recommendation>
      <Recommendation>
         <UserName>username1</UserName>
         <RestaurantId>restaurantid4</RestaurantId>
      </Recommendation>
      <Recommendation>
         <UserName>username1</UserName>
         <RestaurantId>restaurantid5</RestaurantId>
      </Recommendation>
      <Recommendation>
         <UserName>username3</UserName>
         <RestaurantId>restaurantid1</RestaurantId>
      </Recommendation>
      <Recommendation>
         <UserName>username4</UserName>
         <RestaurantId>restaurantid7</RestaurantId>
      </Recommendation>
      <Recommendation>
         <UserName>username5</UserName>
         <RestaurantId>restaurantid8</RestaurantId>
      </Recommendation>
   </Recommendations>
</ReviewApplication>
```

EDIT-- Expected result:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>HW 5.10</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Reviews with Details</h1>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>RestaurantName</th>
        <th>FirstName</th>
        <th>Rating</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>restaurant1</td>
        <td>first1</td>
        <td>4.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>restaurant2</td>
        <td>first1</td>
        <td>5.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>restaurant4</td>
        <td>first1</td>
        <td>4.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>restaurant5</td>
        <td>first1</td>
        <td>1.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>restaurant1</td>
        <td>first2</td>
        <td>2.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>restaurant7</td>
        <td>first2</td>
        <td>3.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>restaurant8</td>
        <td>first2</td>
        <td>4.0</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't post the result you expect to get. If you just want to list the reviews along with the names of the restaurant and the user, you could do simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:key name="user" match="User" use="UserName" />
<xsl:key name="restaurant" match="Restaurant" use="RestaurantId" />

<xsl:template match="/ReviewApplication">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Reviews with Recommendations</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>RestaurantName</th>
                    <th>FirstName</th>
                    <th>Rating</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="Reviews/Review">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="key('restaurant', RestaurantId)/Name"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="key('user', UserName)/FirstName"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Rating"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: sorry! Just added the expected result!

Comment: Well, it looks identical to the one I get.